# Internet Explorer 11 issue

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I am working on selenium automation through IE web browser. Sometimes while invoking browser the actions are done very slowly.

For example, If I comment a user id(abcd), IE typing like a(taking a minute)b(taking minute),c(taking a minute)..... I checked the internet speed and clear the cache cookies and all. Sometimes it's happening.

Please suggest any solutions.

Comment: you understand that this is way too vague for us to even start guessing?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: What are your binary versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it is due to 64 bit IEWebDriver. Switch to 32 bit IEWebDriver and check if it fixes your issue.